# Why an open triangle is a 2-dimensional Borel set in $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For example, $\{(x,y)\in R^2: 0<y<x, 0 < x < 1  \}$. I googled and found some proofs. Basically their logic is, since every rectangle is a Borel set, we can bisect rectangles to fill the triangle.

However, I am not convinced. To fill the triangle, for each point on the subspace $\{(x,y) \in R^2: x=y, 0< x < 1 \}$, there must be one rectangle. Therefore, the number of rectangles is at least uncountable, because the numbers on $\{x\in R: 0< x < 1\}$ are uncountable.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your use of the word 'open triangle'.  The set you describe is more like a trapezoid extending infinitely-downward with a single 'open' edge from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ (said another way, it looks like a trapezoid with 'vertices' $(0,0)$, $(1,1$), $(0,-\infty)$, $(1,-\infty)$ with only the upper-most edge open).  This set is certainly Borel, but it might not be what you're trying to deal with

Comment: @Hayden Sorry, it is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're working from the bare-bones definition of Borel, starting from rectangles - pretty restrictive, but you've got to start somewhere. So here's a covering with rectangles:

For any point $(x,y)$ in the triangle, we have $y < x$. Because the rationals are dense, there exists a rational $q$ with $y < q < x$. Let $R_q$ be the open rectangle with vertices $(q,q)$, $(1,q)$, $(1,0)$, and $(q,0)$. This rectangle covers $(x,y)$. Now, for every point in the triangle there is such a $q$, so the union of all these rectangles covers everything - but even though there are uncountably many points, there are only countably many $R_q$. So $T$ is the union of open rectangles $R_q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, which makes $T$ Borel.

I'm assuming here you meant to say that the triangle ends at $y = 0$ - if not, and you meant for the "triangle" to extend into an infinite vertical strip below the horizontal axis, then just stretch all the rectangles vertically. I'm also assuming you meant to say $0 < x < 1$, not $0 \leq x \leq 1$, in which case the triangle is not open. It would still be Borel, though, just a little trickier to show.

Comment: So the key argument here is that, since $Q$ is dense in $R$, for every point in $R$, there is always a rectangle that covers it, and the rectangle is numbered by a rational number, which means some irrational numbers can share the same rectangle. This is pretty convincing. Thanks!